# Accessing the UI thread from a Socket AsyncCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

I'm pretty new to multithreading, and even Socket programming, but bear with me: Currently I'm receiving messages from another computer using Socket.BeginReceive, and they're being received fine.

However the key thing I want to do using the received information is update the UI. (or rather the data bound to the UI) However the program crashes if I try to do that, and I expect that's because the AsyncCallback delegate runs on a separate thread. What's the standard procedure for accessing main window variables (I'm using WPF) from another thread?  I've read vague things about using BeginInvoke(), but I don't have access to the main window at all, so I don't understand how to use invoking here.

Thanks for any help!

The relevant code is like this:

```
Listener.BeginReceive(Recieved, 0, Recieved.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   TextBox_1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Are you using .Net 4.5? If so, give some consideration to moving to Task based asynchrony using `async/await` and save yourself some brain pain.

Comment: Just .net 4 I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate things on UI thread via its dispatcher which you can access via `App.Current.Dispatcher` -

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate { TextBox_1.Text = ""; });
```

Or if you want it to be called asynchronously use BeginInvoke -

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { TextBox_1.Text = ""; });
```